# While creating a React app, process stops and shows 4983 low severity vulnerablity (run npm audit to fix them)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Creating a new React app in E:\hello\jj.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall E:\hello\jj\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall E:\hello\jj\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall E:\hello\jj\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ react@16.13.1
added 1602 packages from 751 contributors and audited 1606 packages in 128.871s

61 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 4981 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

i have tried all the methods for creating app
`npm install create-react-app -g`,
`npx create-react-app app-name`,
`create-react-app app-name`.

the app it created has only => a node_module folder,a package file and package_lock file

Comment: The process doesn't just "stop", it's *finished*.

Comment: then what should i do ,for creating app setup

Comment: Did you actually try using the app it created? Have you had a specific *problem*?

Comment: it has only created node_modules folder,package file and package-lock file.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with that context, then. Outline the problem, show your research - see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the windows,resetting the pc worked for me,now my process doesn't finished at **run npm audit fix**,now creates all the required folders and files